# Apache FOP Renders wrong size of images

Tags: javascript, pdf, d3.js, svg, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP to render a svg image from my application to PDF.

Lets say i have this image:

```
<svg id="drawingSpace" height="965" width="717" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image id="782" y="434.9338297750881" x="236.63121279426443" width="30" height="30" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7680249/iconBlueGreenStrokeRectangle.svg" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
</svg>
```

If i look at it in a browser, this is completely correct, it's size is 30x30 pixels. But of course the SVG Image i'm loading has a different size. I created it with Batik and uploaded it to my dropbox, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
          'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg style="stroke-dasharray:none; shape-rendering:auto; font-family:'Dialog'; text-rendering:auto; fill-opacity:1; color-interpolation:auto; color-rendering:auto; font-size:12px; fill:black; stroke:black; image-rendering:auto; stroke-miterlimit:10; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-style:normal; stroke-width:1; stroke-dashoffset:0; font-weight:normal; stroke-opacity:1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" contentStyleType="text/css" height="250"
><!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--><defs id="genericDefs"/>
    <g>
        <g style="fill:rgb(60,123,190); stroke:rgb(60,123,190);">
            <rect x="12" width="225" height="225" y="12" style="stroke:none;"/>
        </g>
        <g style="fill:lime; stroke-width:25; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke:lime;">
            <rect x="12" width="225" height="225" y="12" style="fill:none;"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, this image is 250x250 pixels big, which i assume is the same size it has in my generated pdf.

I generate the pdf in another class like this

```
Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
    // Setup input
    Reader in = new java.io.StringReader(svg);

    try {
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(in);
        // Setup output
        try {
            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(out);
            // Do the transformation
            transcoder.transcode(input, output);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
```

Where svg is the String i give this transcoder.

Is it possible to get FOP to render the images the size they are in the browser or containing svg?

If i exchange the svg to a png picture it works perfectly.

My application renders those svg/png pictures like this. I'm using d3js.

```
var points = this.plot.selectAll("image").data(this.projectMap.mainTasks);
      points.enter().append("svg:image")
        .attr("y", (d:rest.ProjectMapMainTaskResource) => {
          return this.yScale(d.position) - 5;
        })
        .attr("x", (d:rest.ProjectMapMainTaskResource) => {
          return this.xScale(d.date) - 5;
        })
        .attr("width", "30")
        .attr("height", "30")
        .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7680249/iconBlueGreenStrokeRectangle.svg");
      points.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Try giving the SVG a viewBox

Comment: I would think you problem is in the whole concept. A "pixel" is an interpretive unit of measure to the system used. To a browser a pixel is likely different than what FOP interprets a pixel as. And setting dimensions this way (without units) means pixels ... height="965" width="717"

Comment: Giving the SVG a viewBox seems to be the answer, thank you Robert.